# como mostrar por separado un entero y un float? 2,83 print (2) print (83)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numero = int(input("Ingresa un numero:"))
h= str("minutos")
#min= numero//60
print (min)
print (h)
dec = round((numero*60),2)
```

#### Ejercicio 1.4

Escribe un código en el que solicite por pantalla que el usuario introduzca un número (las unidades son segundos).  Una vez introducido el número calcula:

1. Número de minutos del valor introducido
2. Número de segundos restantes.

Imprime por pantalla ambos valores.

Ejemplo: si el usuario introduce 90, eso imprimiría 1 minuto y 30 segundos.

**Tip:** Lee sobre la función `input()`

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
     numero = int(input("Ingresa un numero:"))
     min = int(número/60)
     seg = int(numero%60)
     print("%s minuto y %s segundos" % (min, seg))
except:
     print("valor ingresado no es válido")
```

Comment: hola Jimy, gracias por responder pero solo codigo es considerado de baja calidad. por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir explicacion del funcionamiento. Mira [answer] para más info . Un saludo